# DatabaseLookup hangs on specific values

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle

I use Kettle for some transformations and ran into a problem:
For one specific row, my DatabaseLookup step hangs. It just doesn't give a result. Trying to stop the transformation results in a never ending "Halting" for the lookup step.

The value given is nothing complicated at all, neither it is different from all other rows/values. It just won't continue.

Doing the same query in the database directly or in a different database tool (e.g. SQuirreL), it works.

I use Kettle/Spoon 4.1, the database is MySQL 5.5.10. It happens with Connector/J 5.1.14 and the one bundled with spoon.

The step initializes flawlessly (it even works for other rows) and I have no idea why it fails. No error message in the Spoon logs, nothing on the console/shell.

Answer (score 0):

weird. Whats the table type? is it myisam?  Does your transform also perform updates to the same table? maybe you are locking the table inadvertantly at the same time somehow?

Or maybe it's a mysql 5.5 thing..  But ive used this step extensively with mysql 5.0 and pdi 4.everything and it's always been fine...  maybe post the transform?

Comment: No locking, I can even cut the transformation down to that one failing step.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the culprit:
The lookup takes as a result the id field and gave it a new name, PERSON_ID. This FAILS in some cases! The resulting lookup/prepared statement was something like

```
select id as PERSON_ID FROM table WHERE ...
```

SOLUTION:
Don't use underscore in the "New name" for the field! With a new name of PERSONID everything works flawlessly for *ALL* rows!

Stupid error ...

Comment: OK, I have to revise my answer: It is the part which acts as "...AS..." in the SQL statement, but it seems like the underscore is not the (only) problematic character. I now have a reproduceable situation where the new name for the field works if it is called newfieldname but the transformation hangs if it is called newFieldName. Very strange - seems like I have to look into the Kettle code at times.

Comment: Strange indeed! make sure you raise a jira for it! jira.pentaho.com

Comment: I haven't encountered it again, not sure whether it was a database problem (the db is not within my administrative scope) or a kettle one. But if it occurs again, I will try to create a reproducable issue for the Jira.